# django form error : Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'

Tags: django, django-forms

Model:

```
class AppUser(models.Model) :
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now=True)
    hobbies = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    education_level = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    identifier = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

class Student(models.Model):
    appuser = models.ForeignKey(AppUser , unique=True)
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution , blank=True, null=False)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, blank=True, null=True)
    institute_email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Forms:

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm):
    institute_id = forms.CharField()
    institution = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Institution.objects.all())
    course = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COURSE_CHOICES)
    education_level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=EDUCATION_LEVELS)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        exclude = ('appuser','department', 'is_valid')
```

Views:

```
student_formset = inlineformset_factory(AppUser,Student,fields=('institution', \
'course', 'institute_email', 'identifier', 'education_level'),form=StudentForm)

if request.POST:
    student_form = student_formset(request.POST, instance=user)
    if student_form.is_valid():
```

Template:

```
<form method='post' action='#student'>
{{ student_form.management_form }}
{% for form in student_form.forms %}
    <p>{{ form}}</p>
{% endfor %}
 </form>
```

Error:

```
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'
```

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/add_details/
Django Version:     1.2.4
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'
.....

Template error
....
Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'

**It shows problem in template code..**

**If in template instead of rendering {{form}} we use {{form.as_p}} then it outputs nothing.**

Any ideas on above issue??

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it by removing 'auto_now_add' from date fields... (but I didn't find why)

Answer (score 0):

I believe here:

```
student_formset = inlineformset_factory(AppUser,Student,fields=('institution', \
'course', 'institute_email', 'identifier', 'education_level'),form=StudentForm)
```

`identifier` does not exists... is nothing, none, null etc ... remove it! :)
`education_level` also!

Or, subclass Student to AppUser!

```
class Student(AppUser):
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, 
indentifier and education_level were essential fields.. Subclass approach is a solution.. but on different lines from what the current model is..

Comment: The error was removed by changing the student_formset initialization:


    `student_formset = inlineformset_factory(AppUser,Student,fields=('institution', 'course', 'institute_email', 'identifier', 'education_level'),form=StudentForm)`

was changed to

`student_formset = inlineformset_factory(AppUser,Student,form=StudentForm)`